# rails endless scroll with kaminari, event not triggering

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari, railscasts

Fallowed the endless scrolling tutorial by Ryan Bates, and don't understand why it's not working ;/ partial does not update

**localfeeds/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="infinite-table">
            <%=render :partial => 'scribbles/scribbles', :locals => {:scribbles => @scribbles}%>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<%= paginate @scribbles %>
```

**localfeeds.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
     if $('.pagination').length
          $(window).scroll ->
                  url = $('.pagination .next a').attr('href')
                  if url &&  $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
                          alert("test2")
                          $('.pagination').text('Fetching more products...')
                          $.getScript(url)
     $(window).scroll()
```

**localfeeds/show.js.erb**

```
// Append new data
$('#infinite_table').append('<%= j render(:partial => 'scribbles/scribbles', :scribbles => @scribbles) %>');

<% if (@scribbles.current_page < @scribbles.num_pages) %>
$('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j paginate(@scribbles) %>');
<% else %>
$('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

Please help

Safari HTML render
[image: html render error part]

Comment: Ensure your JS is being loaded and is running by putting `console.log([string or param])` at the beginning and end of JS/CS files. They should appear in your Firefox/Firebug or Chrome console. Also check the console for any JS errors.

Can you post the rendered mark-up?

Comment: the localfeeds.js.coffee is loaded, moved the alert('test') to the top and it popped up and it appears in firebug. adding console.log([string or param]) to js throws an error, it's the only js error that I'm getting in firebug.

Comment: Apologies, I meant for [string or param] to be replaced with either a string, like "Woo! Made it!" or a param like $('#infinite_table') or something. If you put a complex object into console.log you'll be able to navigate it in the console.

Comment: still don't get any errors pointing to a problem

Comment: If you post the rendered mark-up I can look for any JQuery selector mistakes you may have missed. In the meantime you can use console.log and the console as a tool to analyse your code. Do you know if localfeeds/show.js.erb is being executed? You can use a console.log in there as well. Or an alert if you must ;)

Comment: it seems that It works, i can trigger it with this: '<%= link_to_next_page(@scribbles, 'Next Page', :remote => true)%>' . but the local feeds.js.coffee doesn't seem to register the scrolling down.

Comment: what HTML does that link_to generate?

Comment: '<p class="pagination">
       <a href="/localfeeds/1?page=2" data-remote="true" rel="next">Next Page</a>
 </p>'

Comment: OK, do you get an alert when the scroll hits the bottom as your code would suggest? If you replace the look-up in that part of the code with the url from that button, does it work? `url = $('.pagination .next a').attr('href');` -> `url = "/localfeeds/1?page=2"`.

Finally, I need to see the `<span class="next"` tag opened up in your html.

Comment: Nope, the alert doesn't come up, but the file is definitely loaded, the alert comes up when it is moved to the very top of the file :( here is the next button: ` <a href="/localfeeds/1?page=2" rel="next">Next ›</a> `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58263/discussion-between-a-fader-darkly-and-richardlonesteen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localfeeds/show.js.erb

```
// Append new data
$('#infinite_table').append(...
```

but in your HTML you have:

```
<div id="infinite-table" ....
```

The first uses _, the second -

EDIT:

From your comments it looks like the error is in your scroll detection code. Try this, and look at the console output for clues:

```
jQuery ->
     console.log("Creating pagination callback")
     if $('.pagination').length
          console.log("Pagination detected")
          $(window).scroll ->
                  console.log("Scroll detected")
                  url = $('.pagination .next a').attr('href')
                  if url &&  $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
                          console.log("Url found: " + url)
                          $('.pagination').text('Fetching more products...')
                          $.getScript(url)
                          console.log("Script loaded")
     $(window).scroll()
```

Which, if any, of the console log statements lead to entries in the console log? What happens when you scroll the page?

Comment: yeah that was one of the problems. But it still isn't updating as i scroll down. if I add a button like that '<%= link_to_next_page(@scribbles, 'Next Page', :remote => true)%>' it triggers the show.js.erb and ajax renders another page.

Comment: It didn't record any of the messages in the development.log ;/

Comment: You need to look in the console tab of your browser's inspector. Assuming you're using Chrome, right-click on any element and select 'Inspect Element'. You get a new panel with some tabs, including one called 'console'. Look in there while you load the page and scroll around.

Comment: here is the silliest thing ever, because of spaces and indentations the code didn't work. Now it sort of does, [Log] Scroll detected (localfeeds.js, line 14)
[Log] Url found: /localfeeds/1?page=2 (localfeeds.js, line 17)
[Log] Script loaded (localfeeds.js, line 20)
[Log] Scroll detected (localfeeds.js, line 14, x1472) but it doesn't go pass page 2 :(

Comment: What happens when you type that into the console window? `$.getScript('/localfeeds/1?page=2')`

Comment: if i write $.getScript('/localfeeds/1?page=2/3/4/5/6/7') I get a new object and it renders scribbles.

Comment: I think i solved it, had a mistake in show.js.erb. It's all good. THANK YOU SIR !!!!!!!

Comment: I love a happy ending.

Answer (score 0):

Just an observation, but where is $(window).scroll() being called apart from once in the initialisation code?

Code creates the method if there is pagination data and then calls it once regardless - where does it get called again? Also if there is no pagination data the first call to scroll will break ...

I can't unpick this without more code and it might just be I have an incomplete picture.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

window.scroll sets a handler. The immediate call ensures the first wave of results are loaded if needs be.

Comment: thanks - it would be one of those d'oh moments otherwise :) I wonder if there are any console errors stopping this loading/happening ...?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fg2qlaeflnrb8ax/development.log here is a development log

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Localfeed with id=[object Object]:
Looks like there may be a 500 error that might be breaking things

Comment: [object Object] is coming from js - it means an object is being used where it expects a string or number

Comment: Yeah - but is that coming into the JS interpreter as an unhandled error? That might be what's breaking the scroll ...